# Database Importing Collation

Tags: mysql, character-set, utf-8

Migrating from DB2 found this error message:

```
Error message: Incorrect string value: '\xF2\xAC\x9F\xB0or...' for column 'column_name'
```

This is when trying to import an XML to MySQL. I should have a longtext column with UTF-8 encoding:

> MySQL does not have this option, so you'll have to use the TEXT datatype using a UTF-8 character set.
>   [View Full Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456776/problems-of-handling-xml-datatypes-with-mysql)

I tried to change the character set of the column to 'utf8mb4' which would support 4 byte length characters. And also set the character_set_server to utf8mb4. But it doesn't work.

> If you have MySQL 5.5 or later you can change the column encoding from utf8 to utf8mb4. This encoding allows storage of characters that occupy 4 bytes in UTF-8. 
>   You may also have to set the server property character_encoding_server to utf8mb4 in the MySQL configuration file. [View full question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957238/incorrect-string-value-when-trying-to-insert-utf-8-into-mysql-via-jdbc)

Is there anything else i could try?

MySQL Version: 5.6.13
Connection via: JDBC
OS: Microsoft Windows 7

Comment: I think that F2 is off beyond anything that is currently defined in utf8.  Sure, the bits seem valid, but what character are you expecting for F2AC9FB0 ?

Comment: Thank you Rick. I really don't know what kind of information is, i only know that is a xml field. I'm not much familiar to encodings or character sets.

Comment: Go to the source of the XML and ask them.  Also, can you tell who is issuing the error message?  Perhaps Java?

Comment: Yes, it's Java, it connects to both databases using jdbc driver....